# Bind Exception not thrown

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws

I am working on Spring Web Services. For some reason if my inputs in xml are not in proper format, it is not throwing bind exception. Instead it just assigns null and proceeds. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few weeks ago I was having same problem. The web services that I am trying to use was using Apache Axis 1.4 version and there was a bug related to List objects in Axis. But web services was not belong to us so We reported and requested new bug-free versions and problem disappeared.

My suggestion is first use SOAP UI and confirm you get the xml when you request with proper parameters.Then check for empty or incorrect namespaces .

Comment: I'm getting proper response for valid inputs

Comment: I have updated my answer. Did you check xml namespaces from response?

Comment: I will check that and let you know